# AWS EB CLI - not able to select from existing application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS and AWS EB CLI. My organisation already has an application hosted in AWS and they use AWS EB CLI for deployment. I have installed awsebcli

```
brew install awsebcli
```

And the installation is successful.

```
  eb --version
```

outputs

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.20.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ebcli/display/screen.py:442: SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?
assert(
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.20.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/create.py:221: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
if instance_types is "":
EB CLI 3.20.0 (Python 3.9.6)
```

Now I did cd to the application which is already hosted in AWS and updated my .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

```
  branch-defaults:
 master:
    environment: xxxx-staging
environment-defaults:
  xxxx-staging:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: xxxx
  default_ec2_keyname: xxxx-eb
  default_platform: Puma with Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux
  default_region: xx-xxxxx-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

When I do eb init from the application I am not asked to

```
Select an application to use: choose
```

I am always asked to

```
Enter Application Name
```

And I am not able to select from the existing application. Is it related to access issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because I do not have access to the existing applications in the AWS EB. Once access is granted, I am able to select from existing application.